# Matching different digits after a lookahead

Tags: regex

Say I have the following:

Regex: `(?<=([sS][\d]{1,2}[eE]))(?(?=0)[1-9]{1}|[\d]{2})` 
Text: `FooBar.S02E03.foo`

how do I get the first part of the if to match only the '3' of the E03?

What I'm trying to get here is a regex that matches only the second digit after the 'E' if the first digit after the 'E' is 0, otherwise match both digits after the 'E'.

Comment: Can there be more than two digits after `E`, and if so, what should happen then?

Comment: Yeah, there can be more digits than that and in the case that there is, they should just be part of the match aswell. Didn't consider that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works - is that what you're looking for? This will always stop the match after the second digit (if that's not necessary, it's unclear why you would need such a complicated regex in the first place).

```
(?<=[sS]\d{1,2}[eE](0)?)(?(1)[1-9]|[1-9]\d)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=             # Lookbehind:
 [sS]\d{1,2}[eE] # SddE
 (0)?            # Match a zero if present
)                # End of lookbehind
(?(1)            # If the zero matched...
 [1-9]           # match a single digit (1-9)
|                # If it didn't match...
 [1-9]\d         # match two digits (1-9 and another one)
)                # End of conditional
```

Comment: Actually, I'd mark hwnd's deleted answer as the answer as it was basically what I needed.
The reason it ended up being so complicated was because I've never known about capturing groups before, so that's always good to learn about. Yours works too though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can skip all of the complexity of if-checks. Simply eat any leading zeros after S or E like this:

`echo FooBar.S02E03.foo | sed -r 's/(.*)\.S0*([0-9]{1,2})E0*([0-9]{1,2})\.(.*)/title:\1, season:\2, episode:\3, postfix:\4/'`

`title:FooBar, season:2, episode:3, postfix:foo`

Answer (score 0):

Taking what you had originally, and adding to it, you could have:

```
(?<=([sS]))([\d]{1,2}[eE])(?(?=0)[0][1-9]{1}|[\d]{2})
```

I've taken the \d out of the lookbehind as it's not possible to check if 1 or 2 digits.  Then for the second section, in the if statement I've added the zero before the [1-9], to complete the regex

I've tested this with the inputs:

> S02E03 
>   S02E14

on http://regex101.com/, it's a very handy tool for checking out the regex before using it

Answer (score 0):

@Time Pietzcker 's solution is good enough but does not work for the regex engine without the support of Lookbehind with quantifiers. The below provides a solution with the simple regex engine, and it uses non-capturing group and \K to bypass the limitations.

```
(?<=[sS])(?:\d{1,2}[eE](0)?)\K(?(1)[1-9]|[1-9]\d)
```

Comment: How do you know he's using a flavor that supports `\K`?  There aren't many that do.