# Extract digits after matching the certain string second time

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to extract the digits after second occurance of under score `_` from  a pattern.

by following the similar posts here

[Matching different digits after a lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099231/matching-different-digits-after-a-lookahead)

[regex - return all before the second occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449564/regex-return-all-before-the-second-occurrence)

I tried

```
    library(stringr)

  pattern <- c("1/2/3_500k/855kk_1400k/AVBB")

  str_extract(pattern, "(^_){2}(\\d+\\.*\\d*)")
```

which outputs

> [1] NA

instead of `1400`. Could you help?

Comment: `read.table(text = gsub('[^0-9_]', '', pattern), sep = '_')[, 3L]` could also work

Comment: If you want to extract the digits after the last `_` try [`.*_\K[.\d]+`](https://regex101.com/r/H0sFaX/1) with `perl=TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a base R solution with `regexpr`/`regmatches`:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("^(?:[^_]*_){2}[^_0-9]*\\K\\d*\\.?\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
```

Or, with `sub`:

```
sub("^(?:[^_]*_){2}[^_0-9]*(\\d*\\.?\\d+).*", "\\1", x)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/U51fWv).

The regex is

```
^(?:[^_]*_){2}[^_0-9]*\K\d*\.?\d+
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qRcZf1/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^_]*_){2}` - 2 repetitions of

  - `[^_]*` - any 0+ chars other than `_`
  - `_` - an underscore
- `[^_0-9]*` - any 0+ chars other than `_` and digits
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\d*\.?\d+` - a float or integer number pattern (0+ digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits).

In the `sub` regex variation, the `\K` is not necessary, the number pattern is captured into a capturing group and the rest of string is matched with `.*` pattern. The result is the contents of Group 1, referred to with the `\1` placeholder.

Comment: One question though is it have to be  a complex solution all the time ? For example I could not see `?:` pattern in the [regexcheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) . And could not catch `(?:[^_]*_){2}` part.

Comment: @Alexander I am not the author of the regex cheatsheet you link to, the non-capturing group is the natural way of grouping some atoms/subpatterns that you need to repeat. Since we want to match up to the second `_`, `(?:[^_]*_){2}` does exactly that, without capturing the value. It is not complex. After the second `_`, you want to get to the number, thus `[^_0-9]*` is also a very quick way to do it. If the number is always an integer, replace `\\d*\\.?\\d+` with `\\d+`. Again, those patterns are all well-known, nothing complex.

Comment: I got an for the `regex` solution   Error: '\K' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""^(?:[^_]*_){2}[^_0-9]*\K"

Comment: @Alexander Do not use `str_extract`, ICU library does not support `\K` construct, use the base R `regmatches` with `regexpr` with `perl=TRUE`. Better use the `sub` variation, it must be the quickest. If you want, use `str_replace(x, "^(?:[^_]*_){2}[^_0-9]*(\\d*\\.?\\d+).*", "\\1")`

Comment: Then how should I use regex solution ?

Comment: Exactly as I wrote in the answer. Or `str_replace(x, "^(?:[^_]*_){2}[^_0-9]*(\\d*\\.?\\d+).*", "\\1")`

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One option could be as:

```
pattern <- c("1/2/3_500k/855kk_1400k/AVBB")
sub(".*_*_(\\d+).*","\\1", pattern, perl = TRUE)
[1] "1400"
```

The `regex` is:

```
".*_*_(\\d+).*"
```

**Details:**

- `.*_` anything before first `_`
- `.*_` anything after first  `_` and before 2nd `_`
- `\\d+` look for digits and take those as selection.
- `.*` anything afterwards.

`\\1` replaces matching strings with values found for 1st group.

Comment: what does `\\1` mean ?And could you explain other parts ?

Comment: @Alexander The digits after second `_` is enclosed in '()` to represent the selection group. `"\\1"` represents replacing the matched string with first group of value e.g (enclosed in `()`).