# Matching a single numeric digit after the second period of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a series of data that I would like to extract a single digit from. I will be using python to execute the regex.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470115/extract-digits-after-matching-the-certain-string-second-time) previous post looked promising, but I couldn't get anything working as of yet. More specifically I would like the first numeric digit after the second "." of each string.

This is my attempted regex:  [[^.]*[^.]*?([0-9])](https://regex101.com/r/Xe8KfL/2)

The below example includes test data with the targeted number in bold. I plan to use this to iterate through a table, so it only needs to work for each individual string, not all of them at once.

Example data:

> AR0.RRPG.**1**05
>
> AR6.TR0.**5**00
>
> AR0.GGF0.**2**FEH
>
> AR0.DER.M**1**5

Comment: Please add your attempted regex

Comment: A couple things. First, in most languages, you can't have a variable length lookahead which is generally how you check if something comes before what you're looking for without actually matching it. What language you're using matters in this case. You can use groups to get around this, but again, depends on the language. Another method would be to use the `$` character at the very end to signify your match comes directly before the end of the string, but that is contingent on the last section always being right before a line break. Could add these two details to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*?([0-9])`](https://regex101.com/r/4WX3qH/3)

- First as many non-dot characters as possible up to the first dot
- Same up to the second dot
- Finally as few non-dot characters as possible, up to the first digit, which is captured

Comment: I would anchor it to the start AND simplify the last step: `^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.([0-9])`

Comment: @Enissay Yes, anchoring is a good idea. Your simplification of the last step wouldn't work for `AR0.DER.M15` however.

Comment: Oh, true, I really missed that last example. I thought all digits were immediately after the dot. Good point indeed

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a long string of non digits first following after the last dot (before reaching the first digit), you can also exclude matching both a dot and a digit in the negated character class `[^.\d]*` to prevent some backtracking.

```
^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.\d]*(\d)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iq0dLf/1).

**Note** that you don't have to escape the `\.` in the character class, and the using `[^.]` can also match a newline.